# Close overlay by clicking outside overlay, Highlight overlay button when overlay active

Tags: javascript, html, css

Currently the Overlay only closes upon clicking button 'X'. I would like it to close when clicking outside the overlay or if the page is refreshed.
The other thing I have tried at least 100 times and miserably failed, is to keep the hover effect (color #F00) intact when the overlay is active. I have tried
    .active{ 
    color:#F00; 
        }
but it seems that this only works for the split second the link is clicked on.

The Javascript is as following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggleOverlay(){
    var overlay = document.getElementById('overlay');
    var specialBox = document.getElementById('specialBox');
    overlay.style.opacity = .7;
    if(overlay.style.display == "block"){
        overlay.style.display = "none";
        specialBox.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        overlay.style.display = "block";
        specialBox.style.display = "block";
    }
</script>
```

The CSS is as following:

```
<style type="text/css">
div#overlay {
    display: none;
    z-index: 2;
    background: #A9A9A9;
    position: fixed;
    width: 879px;
    height: 291px;
    top: 50px;
    left: 0px;
    text-align: center;
}
div#specialBox {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 3;
    width: 719px; 
    height: 215px;
    top: 88px;
    left: 80px;
    background: #FFF;
}
div#wrapper {
    position:absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    padding-left: 24px;
}
</style>

<style type="text/css">
    .btn {
        cursor:pointer;
        font-size:24px;
        border:none;
        color:#000
}
    .btn:hover{ 
    color:#F00; 
    }
</style>

<style type="text/css">
    .x {
        background-color:white;
        cursor:pointer;
        font:Arial;
        font-size:14px;
        color:red;
        z-index: 4;
        position: fixed;
        top: 92px;
        left: 766px;
</style>
```

The HTML is as following:

```
<!-- Start Overlay -->
<div id="overlay"></div>
<!-- End Overlay -->
<!-- Start Special Centered Box -->
<div id="specialBox">
  <button class="x" onmousedown="toggleOverlay()">X</button>
</div>
<!-- Start Special Centered Box -->
<!-- Start Normal Page Content -->
<div id="wrapper">
  <button class="btn" onmousedown="toggleOverlay()">HIGHEST QUALITY</button>
</div>
<!-- End Normal Page Content -->
```

Your help will be strongly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind this is a quick fix for your problem and wrote it to show you some basics in `javascript`

`document.onclick = function(event)` this triggers on any mouse click on the document.

`var target = getTarget(event);` this calls the function that will return what element was clicked

What the function does

Since all your elements have an `id` we are checking to see if the `id` is blank. If there is no idea it is than outside your elements so close the `div`

I added an `id` to your `button` so we could change the color from black to red

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

function getTarget(event){
    target = (typeof window.event === "undefined")?event.target:window.event.srcElement;
    return target;
}

document.onclick = function(event){
    var target = getTarget(event);
    if(target.id == ""){
        var overlay = document.getElementById('overlay');
        var specialBox = document.getElementById('specialBox');
        var button = document.getElementById('qualityButton');
        overlay.style.display = "none";
        specialBox.style.display = "none";
        button.style.color="#000000";
    }

}


function toggleOverlay(){
    var overlay = document.getElementById('overlay');
    var specialBox = document.getElementById('specialBox');
    var button = document.getElementById('qualityButton');
    overlay.style.opacity = .7;
    if(overlay.style.display == "block"){
        overlay.style.display = "none";
        specialBox.style.display = "none";
        button.style.color="#000000";
    } else {
        overlay.style.display = "block";
        specialBox.style.display = "block";
        button.style.color="#ff0000";
    }
}
</script>

<style type="text/css">

div#overlay {
    display: none;
    z-index: 2;
    background: #A9A9A9;
    position: fixed;
    width: 879px;
    height: 291px;
    top: 50px;
    left: 0px;
    text-align: center;
}
div#specialBox {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 3;
    width: 719px; 
    height: 215px;
    top: 88px;
    left: 80px;
    background: #FFF;
}
div#wrapper {
    position:absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    padding-left: 24px;
}
</style>

<style type="text/css">
    .btn {
        cursor:pointer;
        font-size:24px;
        border:none;
        color:#000
}
    .btn:hover{ 
    color:#F00; 
    }
</style>

<style type="text/css">
    .x {
        background-color:white;
        cursor:pointer;
        font:Arial;
        font-size:14px;
        color:red;
        z-index: 4;
        position: fixed;
        top: 92px;
        left: 766px;
    }
</style>

</head>

<body>
<!-- Start Overlay -->
<div id="overlay"></div>
<!-- End Overlay -->
<!-- Start Special Centered Box -->
<div id="specialBox">
  <button class="x" onmousedown="toggleOverlay()">X</button>
</div>
<!-- Start Special Centered Box -->
<!-- Start Normal Page Content -->
<div id="wrapper">
  <button id="qualityButton" class="btn" onmousedown="toggleOverlay()">HIGHEST QUALITY</button>
</div>
<!-- End Normal Page Content -->



</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi N0M3, I've read your answer and will be trying it as soon as I'm back, as I have to go out of the house for a while. Many thanks for taking the time to reply. Will get back to you asap. Thanks again!!

Comment: Hi N0M3, your solution works perfect!! :D Thanks a million for this! Just wanted to know what you meant by 'quick fix'? Also I understand        document.onclick = function(event), however I can't seem to make sense of var target = getTarget(event); Could you possibly explain the latter, as I would love to learn how it works. Thanks again, you're too kind.

Comment: quick fix simply means i wrote it fast and was not optimized in any way or tested, the `getTarget(event)` is used because of `Internet Explorer` sucking so bad. So in order to get reference to the clicked element we need to do a `crossbrowser` check, `IE` references it by `window.event.srcElement`, while real browsers simply use `event.target`. Lots of people have been using jQuery so they have no need to check for browser compatibility.

Comment: @user3677306 umm, there was an error in the code, ive updated it though, this line target = (typeof window.event === "undefined")?event.target:window.event.srcElement; had to be changed, it was giving errors the other way, typed it backwards

Comment: Thanks for this! I've noted that if the overlay is open, and the user clicks another page on the website, and gets back to the original page where the overlay was, the overlay remains open. Is there a way to close it upon leaving the page or refreshing the page, or does one simply have to close an overlay after opening it?

Comment: Thanks for this! I've noted that if the overlay is open, and the user clicks another page on the website, and gets back to the original page where the overlay was, the overlay remains open. Is there a way to close it upon leaving the page or refreshing the page, or does one simply have to close an overlay after opening it?